# is there a way to create generic OIDC SSO framework using python to support all OpenID connect providers

Tags: python, single-sign-on, openid-connect, openid

our requirement is to create a generic SSO framework for OpenID Connect (OIDC) using python. Our framework should support any OpenID provider by changing the client Id and secrets. I have tried using flask-oidc but it still needs the corresponding provider's SDK. Please suggest some framework or libraries

Comment: https://github.com/jpmanson/EasyOIDC?